# Add Custom Field to auth_user table in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication, django-users

**I Want to add my custom TrustAdministration Field to Auth_User table in django**

Here is my **Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Trust(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class TrustAdministration(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        email = moels.CharField(max_length=75)
```

**form.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from models import Trust, TrustAdministration

class TrustForm(form.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Trust

class TrustAdministration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = TrustAdministration

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
```

**view.py**

```
def trust_registration(request):
    if request.POST:
        trust_form = TrustForm(request.POST, instance=Trust())
        trust_admin_form = TrustAdministrationForm(request.POST,instance=TrustAdministration())
        user_form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if trust_form.is_valid() and trust_admin_form.is_valid() and user_form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)   
            new_user.save()
            new_trust = trust_form.save()
            new_trust_admin = trust_admin_form.save(commit = False)
            new_trust_admin.trust = new_trust
            new_trust_admin.user = new_user
            new_trust_admin.email = username
            new_trust_admin.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/registration/trust_registration')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/registration/trust_details')
    else:
        trust_form = TrustForm()
        trust_admin_form = TrustAdministrationForm()
        user_form = UserCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'trust/trust_registration.html', {'trust_form': trust_form,
                                                        'trust_admin_form' : trust_admin_form,
                                                        'user_form' : user_form})
```

When i submit the form it gives error **password is required**, but **Usercreation form shows textfield for password1 and password2 on form.**

And also tell me it is right or wrong way to create a user entry for **TrustAdministration** model.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
email = moels.CharField(max_length=75)
```

It looks like you just misspelled models:

```
email = models.CharField(max_length=75)
```